# Points $S$ and $T$ are on side $\overline{CD}$ of rectangle $ABCD$ such $ \overline{AS}$ and $\overline{AT}$

Tags: area, rectangles, geometry

Points $S$ and $T$ are on side $\overline{CD}$ of rectangle $ABCD$ such $\overline{AS}$ and $\overline{AT}$ trisects $\angle DAB$. If $CT = 3$ and $DS = 6$, then what is the area of $ABCD$?

I have drawn the picture but what can you do next? Are there similar triangles or ratios to do? This question is pretty urgent. It is really hard for me. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $m\angle DAB=90^\circ$, so $m\angle DAS=30^\circ=m\angle SAT=m\angle BAT$. See that $\tan30^\circ=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{6}{DA}$, assuming that $S$ is the point on $CD$ closest to vertex $D$. Thus, $DA={2\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Oh thanks, we've found one side but how about the other side. DS=6 and CT=3 When I drew my rectangle, CT looked equal to ST. Is that true?

Comment: @user139617 Not necessarily.

Comment: ok, if that doesn't work how do you fidn the length of the extra side